# Какие есть встраиваемые скриптовые языки с типизацией?

Tags: c++

Интересуют встраиваемые скриптовые языки.

Для чего мне нужен скриптовый язык:
В программу нужно добавить возможность расширения логики без изменения основного кода.

Почему типизированный:
Указание типов уменьшает количество ошибок и позволяет отлавливать часть на этапе разбора скрипта(а не при исполнении)

Что нужно от языка:

- обязательное указание типов в синтаксисе языка
- возможность создания несколько объектов интерпретатора в одном процессе
- наличие программного интерфейса для отладчика
- поддержка языка в IDE

Что я смотрел:

- `Lua` - без типизации, поддержка типов в IDE через аннотации в комментариях
- `Python` - нельзя создать несколько инстансов в одном процессе, указание типов опционально
- `AngelScript` - отсутствует поддержка в IDE

Наиболее интересен для меня `AngelScript`, но отсутствие поддержки в IDE все портит.

Какие встраиваемые языки еще можно посмотреть?

Comment: С, C++, Pascal, Javascript (Typescript). –

Comment: Компилировать С++ в wasm и встраивать его. :) Не уверен, насколько удобно это делается.

Comment: Еще вопрос кто именно будет расширять логику скриптовым языком. Какой язык эти люди лучше знают. Это конечно ваше дело, но отказ от популярных Lua и Python из-за динамической типизации в пользу какой-нибудь экзотики или более сложного языка, может наоборот усложнить жизнь.

Comment: @Alpensin, у меня очень печальный опыт применения Lua - сотни тысяч строк без указания типов -  Write-Only - очень трудно поддерживать. Python слабо подходит - у него плохо с многопоточностью.

Comment: python,js,lua - остальное всё в лучше избегать так как документация займет больше времени, а без неё просто похороните язык. Как в larnitech - кодишь методом тыка)

Comment: ещё можно какой-нибудь язык из группы скриптшелл (вижал бэйсик скрипт например), если разработка под виндовс.

Comment: @eri нужна кросплатформенность.

Comment: python можно взять в вариации pypy и без GIL если ограничить пользователя потокобезопасными функциями - будет многопоточность. а инстансы можно занеймспейсить и изолировать в одном процессе.

Comment: js хороший вариант, но слишком асинхронный для пользователей.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Немного поискал по запросу `statically typed script languages` и из еще не обсуждавшихся тут обнаружил [daScript](https://dascript.org/), [umka-lang](https://github.com/vtereshkov/umka-lang) и [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) (они про себя пишут -- *"Ch is the most complete, cross-platform C interpreter and C scripting engine in existence"*)

Comment: Также возможно есть смысл поковыряться в [Embeddable Scripting Languages - Awesome Go](https://awesome-go.com/embeddable-scripting-languages/) (наверное, если что-то понравится можно из Go перетянуть в С++)

Comment: Кстати вспомнил, что в [I-DEAS cad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-DEAS) в свое время для кастомизации использовался альтернативный подход. Была возможность компиляции "на лету" Fortran-кода в shared library (подумайте, сейчас компиляторы работают в самом деле очень быстро)

Comment: есть [Lua с типами](https://github.com/dibyendumajumdar/ravi)